# AWS/Heroku Errors out when uploading files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, carrierwave, fog

So, I have a rails/react application that is currently deployed to Heroku. Everything works minus the uploading feature. I switched over from local storage to AWS (CarrierWave/Fog) but it errors out when the PUT request is sent for uploading. Here is what I have...

```
2017-07-26T00:15:26.403722+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7]    (3.9ms)  BEGIN
2017-07-26T00:15:26.409753+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7]   SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "photos") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 4], ["created_at", "2017-07-26 00:15:26.404361"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-26 00:15:26.404361"], ["photos", "[\"15740973_10211933753000319_7147015776553812508_n.jpg\"]"]]
2017-07-26T00:15:27.103871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/photos" host=www.--MY-DOMAIN-NAME--.com request_id=d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7 fwd="76.118.245.207" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3593ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
2017-07-26T00:15:27.099506+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7]    (5.3ms)  ROLLBACK
2017-07-26T00:15:27.100107+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3404ms (ActiveRecord: 13.3ms)
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101564+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7]
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101609+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7] Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101611+00:00 app[web.1]: excon.error.response
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101625+00:00 app[web.1]:   :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>70D9E2369BE5D8A0</RequestId><HostId>qFX1z2eqsP+/Mt9j+uompGs2Z4RRfNDb1ZqMJ6Bfs+ijY8oUEI56XLXeM8kAoWvK276DauKGRYg=</HostId></Error>"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101626+00:00 app[web.1]:   :cookies       => [
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101627+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101628+00:00 app[web.1]:   :headers       => {
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101629+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Connection"       => "close"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101630+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101631+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Date"             => "Wed, 26 Jul 2017 00:15:26 GMT"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101632+00:00 app[web.1]:     "x-amz-id-2"       => "qFX1z2eqsP+/Mt9j+uompGs2Z4RRfNDb1ZqMJ6Bfs+ijY8oUEI56XLXeM8kAoWvK276DauKGRYg="
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101634+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101631+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101633+00:00 app[web.1]:     "x-amz-request-id" => "70D9E2369BE5D8A0"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101635+00:00 app[web.1]:   :host          => "MY-BUCKET-NAME-production.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101636+00:00 app[web.1]:   :local_address => "172.16.75.138"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101636+00:00 app[web.1]:   :local_port    => 50501
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101637+00:00 app[web.1]:   :path          => "/uploads/photo/photos/20/15740973_10211933753000319_7147015776553812508_n.jpg"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101638+00:00 app[web.1]:   :port          => 443
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101638+00:00 app[web.1]:   :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101639+00:00 app[web.1]:   :remote_ip     => "52.219.80.56"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101640+00:00 app[web.1]:   :status        => 403
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101640+00:00 app[web.1]:   :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101641+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101673+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7]
2017-07-26T00:15:27.101718+00:00 app[web.1]: [d2e717f7-5bc0-4832-a441-0f382dffc6c7] app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

`.env file`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = Retracted
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = Retracted
S3_BUCKET             = Retracted
```

`carrierwave.rb` file. Located in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if !Rails.env.test?
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: "AWS",
      aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
      :region => 'us-east-2'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = ENV["S3_BUCKET"]
  end
end
```

My Uploader file, `photos_uploader.rb`

```
class PhotosUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
    if Rails.env.test?
      storage :file
    else
      storage :fog
    end

  ...
```

I have used this method on a previous project and had no issues. The only different between the two is that on the other one I used the built in Heroku Domain name. On this one, I purchased my own domain name and set it up so the DNS pointed to Heroku. I am thinking, possibly that is messing things up, but I am out of ideas at this point.

Running, `heroku run rails c` and then `Photo.all` confirms that nothing is saved to the database.

Comment: You're sure you have given `write` permissions to the user/identity associated with the credentials you're using? That your region is indeed correct along with your bucket name (I imagine you changed it in the log)? That you haven't restricted access to the bucket based on ip's or any other constraints? And btw I think you would be better off with using `carrierwave-aws` instead of `fog` although that isn't relevant here.

Comment: Yes. The user has AmazonSESFullAccess. The bucket name matches up too. I don't know about restricted access but everything should checkout here...

Comment: Are you sure of the Bucket name? `MY-BUCKET-NAME-production.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com` looks strange to me.

Comment: Otherwise, 403 AccessDenied is the first one of the following list of error: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html and means AccessDenied... So if you are pointing to the right bucket, that means that the credentials are incorrect or that you do not have upload privileges.

Comment: Yes. `MY-BUCKET-NAME` is just a placeholder.`-production` is actually part of the bucket name I created. It's `blank-blank-production`. Obviously, don't want to give out the names of my stuff. But, I dont know where or how `.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com` is being appended to that bucket name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a little embarrassed here. Always check for spelling...

The permission I had on my user was `AmazonSESFullAccess`

Which, of course is a lot different that what I wanted - `AmazonS3FullAccess`